# Declined flags on closed questions

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons, flag-reviews

Why are some flags declined when the question is being closed anyway? Is there a set of rules to decide if each flag was helpful when closing? Since the flag drew attention to a question that needed to be closed, isn't it helpful regardless of the type (excepting, of course, spam and offensive flags)?

I ask because I flagged [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/40451/11762) as general reference, since the user could have looked in any dictionary and found the answer (that one of the words is not a verb). The flag was declined, and the question was closed as "not a real question."

Comment: Someone reviewed your flag and disagreed with your reason. Also, I found a dictionary entry where the word *was* used as a verb, so your assertion is incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion it should have been marked "helpful" since the question was ultimately closed -- i.e. the question needed intervention of some kind. Regardless, every moderator has slightly different opinions so keep flagging!

Answer (score 1):

Who marked your flag as invalid is not between the users who voted to close the question. In fact, the question has been closed from 5 users who are not moderators, while just moderators can mark a flag as invalid.
The flag involved different users, who had different opinions on the question; that's all.